# how to calulate Case Quantity from number of quantity in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate case quantity from my no. of quantity of items. just like 
suppose I have 30 beers. my single case of beer contains 12 quantity. so I want calcuate like i have 2.6 case. it means 2 case of 12-12 beers. its 24 and 1 case is of 6 beer. so 2 case and 6 beer. it means 2.6 case.

just like we calculate our experince 3 years and 2 months so its 3.2 years. currently i have calculeted 30/12 so its gives 2.5 but its wrong. its not correct method.

suppose I have 32 beers then case should be 2.8 case and I have to do this calculation with jquery. can anyone please tell me if any formulla exists for this.

ex.

```
var Qty = 30
var case;

-- 1 case contains 12 beer.

so case shold be 2.6 

my current formulla is simple

var case = Qty / 12;
```

but i dont want this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks like your math is wrong on all ends. 30 beers are really 30/12 (2.5) cases. Maybe you want to display a string like `2 cases + 6 beers`?

Comment: yes calculation shold be like that but have to display 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could divide the `beers` by the `case` and round down the result. You can then append the remainder using the modulo operator:

```js
var beers = 32;
var caseSize = 12;

alert(Math.floor(beers / caseSize) + '.' + beers % caseSize); // = '2.8'
```

And to calculate the reverse:

```js
var input = '2.8'.split('.');
var caseSize = 12;

alert(input[0] * caseSize + parseInt(input[1], 10)); // = 32
```

Comment: thank you very much. its works fine. now what to do for reverse process. suppose i have 2.6 case and 1 case contains 12 beer. now i have to calculate no. of quantity so it should be 30. is there any simple formula without split.?

Comment: Not really. You'd need to split by `.` then multiply the case size by the `[0]` item, then add the `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`30/12=2.5` is actually correct. But you can bypass that if you display it as a string like this:

```
var s = parseInt(30/12); 
var s1 = 30%12;
var res = s+"."+s1;
console.log(res)
```

The modulo operator will get the remainder then you concatenate it and get the desired output as a string.

Comment: yes i know 2.5 is correct but its my client's requirement to display results like i said :)

Answer (score 1):

The number of whole cases is:

```
var BEERS_PER_CASE = 12;
var cases = Math.floor(beers / BEERS_PER_CASE);
```

The **remainder** will then be:

```
var remainder_beers = beers - cases * BEERS_PER_CASE; // or "beers % BEERS_PER_CASE"
```

You can then display a string as follows:

```
cases + " cases and " + remainder_beers + " beers"
```

or:

```
cases + "." + beers
```

...if this is how you want to print it out. But mind you, it may be confusing to read 2.6 when it really should be 2.5

Maybe it would be better to use another separator, like `+`:

```
3+11 // 3 cases plus 11 beers
```

Just to distinguish it from standard comma values. But as you have said, the client is king :) If he wants a dot `.` give him what makes him happy!

Comment: yes i know it may be confusing but my clients require this so.

Comment: That's ok. Requirements must be honored :) Copy + paste my code and you should be all set!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the 'remainder' or modulus/modulo

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Using "." generally implies a decimal value.  ie half a case is "0.5", which would be 6 beers, not "0.6" otherwise 33 would be 2.11 which appears to be less than 32 = 2.10 and normally 2.10 = 2.1

So you should provide an alternative representation